# High Velocity Sales- Call Result Picklist

Tags: high-velocity-sales, sales-cadence

I have set up High-velocity-sales in my sandbox. Right now I am facing difficulties while putting call result values after the calling action. As a user, there can be a chance that the user might not know all the values in the call result which can be a problem. It can be great if the call result value is a picklist so that all values will be shown to any user. How can we make call result as a picklist instead of the text box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to Salesforce Article:
"Note that the Call Results field is a text field, so users will need to manually populate the field with the necessary values when they Log a Call. If you wish to automate this for your users, consider using a custom picklist and a process created in Process Builder to populate the value of the Call Results field."

Reference:

Title: Targets do not follow the expected branch after a call is logged in High Velocity Sales
Link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000356597&type=1

An example of how to implement this can be found by following this:

Title: Populate Call Results from a Custom Picklist when not using Dialer
Link: https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#000000000062/a/3y000000Owdl/zsDTK.k8.QJ6cma34.CXWJ9kJkPVd.CkKaM6VN8tShg

Please follow the steps on creating the process builder to map the call results to a custom picklist field.